# Linux diff with minimal match

Tags: linux, diff, match

I need to compare two text files using only linux command lines, to get the list of added lines, removed lines, and modified lines. I currently use `diff --context=0` but if a line is 'modified' and the following line is 'added', these two lines will be marked as 'modified' in a single change set (instead of two change sets: 'modified' for the first and 'added' for the second).

Here is an example of files:

**File#1:**

```
foo line1
```

**File#2:**

```
fooX line1
bar line2
```

**Currently used command:**

```
diff --minimal --context=0 file1 file2
```

**Actual result:**

```
! foo line1
--- 1 ----
! fooX line1
! bar line2
```

**Needed result:**

```
! foo line1
--- 1 ----
! fooX line1

+ bar line2
```

I expected `--minimal` would do the job but it does not. It seems it finds fewer change sets instead of smaller change sets like I need. If I insert a new line containing only "--" just after the first line, it does work, but the files I have to compare are very big and I don't really want to insert "--" between each line...

Comment: Did you notice that the actual output is smaller than your expected output?  So I'd say in terms of _minimal_ the tool hits the nail quite well.  On what grounds do you call your expected output a "better" _minimal_?  Or maybe you can rephrase what you actually expect?

Comment: Ah, and keep in mind that `diff` never analyses the changes _within_ a line (so it does not notice the similarity between `foo line1` and `fooX line`), so the definition of "changed line/block" for `find` is "before is equal and after is equal".  Only if one of the blocks is empty, the "change" is called "insert" or "deletion".

Comment: `man diff` explains that `--minimal` will __"try hard to find a smaller set of changes"__ Does it mean "fewer sets" or "smaller sets" ? (I need _smaller_ sets and I actually have _fewer_ sets)

Comment: @Alfe: I never said the expected output would be "better", it would just be what I need in my case :) As for the size of actual/expected, see my previous comment, it depends on how `man diff` is understood...

Comment: "smaller set of changes" is the same as "fewer changes".

Comment: OK, thank you. I edited my question. 
So, is there any simple solution? (other than a specific bash script...)

Comment: @xav Have you tried a `diff -u`? I'll assume that wasn't what you wanted, so perhaps try [xdelta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xdelta).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `diff -u` does not output `! ...` for modified lines, but both `+ ...` AND `- ...` for each modified line, which makes it difficult to get the lines that are really added or removed (and not modified). I will have a look at xdelta, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there was no suitable solution with `diff`, I generated:

- a file listing all new lines (using another internal processing)
- another file listing deleted lines (using another internal processing)
- the result of `diff --context=0 file1 file2 | grep "^\!"`

Then I filtered the output of the 3rd file by removing all lines that were removed/added:

```
while read line
do
        if ! ( grep -q -- "$line" $ADDED_LINES_FILE $REMOVED_LINES_FILE) ; then
                echo "$line"
        fi
done < diff_output > $TMP_FILE
mv $TMP_FILE diff_output
```